# Why do I have this Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _normalizr.arrayOf) is not a function?

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

I am following a redux tutorial by dan abramov, the code is very simple:

```
import { schema, arrayOf } from 'normalizr';

export const todo = new schema.Entity('todos');
export const arrayOfTodos = arrayOf(todo);
```

but I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _normalizr.arrayOf) is not a function

This is how I am using it in my dispatch:

```
return api.fetchTodos(filter).then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS',
        filter,
        response: normalize(response, schema.arrayOfTodos),
      });
    }
```

I cannot seem to trace the error here, what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error try this:

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

export const todo = new schema.Entity('todos');
export const arrayOfTodos = schema.Array(todo);
```

Not sure about your version of normalizr but based on the [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed) there were some structural changes in the lib itself.

Comment: Thank you for linking the changelogs, I did export const arrayOfTodos = [todo]; and it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

export const todo = new schema.Entity('todos');
export const arrayOfTodos = [todo];
```

This worked for all version of normalizr up to the recent versions